# Is there Gradle "dependencies " task for buildScript dependencies?

Tags: java, gradle

One can run `gradlew dependencies` to learn about dependencies of module tasks. It there a way to find transitive dependencies of **buildscript dependencies**?

Example:
`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'` depends directly on:

```
com.android.tools.build builder
com.android.tools.lint lint
net.sf.proguard proguard-gradle
tools.base project-test-lib
```

As can be seen on [MVNRepository](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.android.tools.build/gradle/1.0.0-rc1). But this artifacts have their own dependencies. Is there and way to find those out without manually traversing whole dependency tree?

As a clarification, the classpath I'm talking about is defined by:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {}
    dependencies { .... }
}
```

Answer (score -7, accepted):

You can use this command:

```
gradle dependencyInsight --dependency gradle
```

There is awesome tutorial by Udacity, [Gradle for Android](https://www.udacity.com/course/viewer#!/c-ud867/l-3968239469/m-4283668596), but you can watch [this video](https://www.udacity.com/course/viewer#!/c-ud867/l-3993908821/m-4302054284) for more explanation.

Comment: "Dependency insight report cannot be generated because the input configuration was not specified.", tried adding `--configuration classpath`, but it still gave me the same error. Also tried `compile` and `runtime` to no avail. Any ideas? (Gradle 3.5)

Comment: This answer is not correct. First, as the above comment mentions, the `dependencyInsight` task requires a configuration name to be provided via the `--configuration` option. Second, only project configurations, not the buildscript configurations, are exposed to this task.

Answer (score 57):

Beginning with Gradle 2.10 you can now get information on buildscript dependencies via

```
gradle buildEnvironment
```

With older versions you'll have to explicitly define a task of type `DependencyReportTask` configured with your build script configuration.

```
task buildscriptDependencies(type: DependencyReportTask) {
    configurations = [buildscript.configurations.classpath]
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, `gradle buildEnvironment` seems to output nothing for core plugins. For example for `apply plugin: 'application'` to dependencies are shown, although the `application` plugin depends on the `java` plugin.

Comment: @sschuberth if you simply what to know what all plugins are used by a build I'd suggest investigate [build scans](https://scans.gradle.com/s/pqarplj4ogagg/plugins). For example https://scans.gradle.com/s/pqarplj4ogagg/plugins.

Comment: With build scans being a public cloud-based service, that would only work if I'm fine with disclosing details about my source code / build system in the open, which sometimes I'm not. I'm aware of the on-premises version with Gradle Enterprise, but I'd really prefer something that works "offline" and creates report on my local disk.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for [Gradle's DependencyInsightReportTask](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.diagnostics.DependencyInsightReportTask.html)

Comment: Can you give an example how to use it to get the report of buildscript dependencies ?

Comment: Just add the task:
task allDepInsight(type: DependencyInsightReportTask) << {}

Then run gradle allDepInsight

Comment: It results in the following error: Execution failed for task ':SdkTestApp:allDepInsight'.
> Dependency insight report cannot be generated because the input configuration was not specified. 
  It can be specified from the command line, e.g: ':SdkTestApp:allDepInsight --configuration someConf --dependency someDep'

Comment: Hm, it seems you need to specify the dependency:
gradle allDepInsight --configuration testRuntime --dependency org.slf4j:slf4j-simple
I don't know how to do it for all the dependecies is the project..

Comment: I can't seem to find configurations, even though the report and docs say there should be some (Using whatever comes with Android Studio v1.5)