# How to prepare a plugin dependency tree in Gradle 5.x?

Tags: java, gradle, groovy, gradle-plugin

How can I have a plugin dependency tree in Gradle 5.x just like a dependency tree ?

Comment: Are you looking for the `buildEnvironment` task?

Comment: @Slaw , that worked for me, provide it in the answer section and i will accept it .

Comment: That's where I found the answer (specifically [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27782159/6395627), not the accepted one).